# How do I set Apex class as Salesforce web service so it can be used as a callback URL for EventNotification of DocuSign?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, docusignapi

I would like to expose an Apex class as a public web service on Salesforce and configure it in the DocuSignAPI.EventNotification as a callback URL for the 'Completed' or 'Signed' event.
Can anyone point me to sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few ways to approach this.  One that I took in a prototype some time ago was to just grab the content of DocuSign's Connect update.  In this scenario I had to create a Site and then create a REST service in Salesforce:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FlexibleConnectListener')
global with sharing class FlexibleConnectListener {
    @HttpPost
    global static String connectUpdate() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        Blob body = req.requestBody;

        Id id = saveUpdate(body);

        String bodyString = body.toString();        
        XMLDom dom = new XMLDom(bodyString);
        List<XMLDom.Element> els = dom.root.getElementsByPath('/DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/EnvelopeStatus/Status');

        return 'Connect update successful.  Status=' + els[0].nodeValue;
    }

    static Id saveUpdate(Blob body) {
        ConnectUpdate__c u = new ConnectUpdate__c();
        insert u;
        Id updateId = u.Id;

        Attachment a = new Attachment();
        a.Body = body;
        a.ParentId = u.Id;
        a.ContentType = 'text/xml';
        a.Name = 'Connect Blob';
        insert a;

        return updateId;
    }
}
```

The connectUpdate() method is there to receive the Connect message and saveUpdate() is just an example of what you might do with it.  In this case it saves the entire request as an attachment on a custom object.  Generally, though, you can process the content however you need.